# Power Automate Office Script Fail on Delete Sheet when the sheet is Very Hidden

Tags: power-automate, office-scripts

I have an issue with a office script that fails with the error message:

This operation is not permitted for the current object.","code":"InvalidOperation","type":"Worksheet","method":"delete","line":16}

```
let wsmacro = workbook.getWorksheet("Macro1");
    // If the worksheet exists, delete it
    if (wsmacro) 
    {
    wsmacro.setVisibility(ExcelScript.SheetVisibility.visible);
    wsmacro.delete();
    return true;} 
    else {
    };`
```

the sheet is set to veryhidden in excel and all the guidance states to make it visible first but it still fails.

Any advice?

the script runs fine in excel online but when called in PA errors out.

Comment: I tested calling this in Power Automate without any issues occurring.